# Given a Multivariate Quotient Ring, can one find a Monoid ring with the same properties?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given a Polynomial ring, say $$S = R[x,y]/(x^2+x-1,y^3-y)$$ Is there a Monoid M and a ring $$T = R[M] \cong S?$$ If there is such a Monoid what would it be? I am able to find one for univariate S:
$R$ is any ring with unity. $$S = R[x]/(p(x)),\qquad n = deg(p)$$ assuming $p(x)$ is monic over $R$. The basis is of $T$ is $B[k]$ with $k \in \Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$,
$R[\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}]$ with the basis action $f(a,b)$ being:
 $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} -c_{k}*B[k+a+b  mod  n] | a+b < \min(a,b) 
\quad \text{or}\quad a+b\quad \text{otherwise}$$

Comment: The product of basis elements must agree with the operation of the monoid, so I don't think $R[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ works for all polynomials of degree $n$. It does work for $M=\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ when $p(x)=x^n-1$ (other polynomials may also work depending on the ring $R$),

Comment: I’ve used sage math to test it my self and it works for any polynomial, the operation is associative as well, with 0 as the unit, I am currently working with R being The Reals or Complexes

Comment: In the ring $R[M]$ with basis $B[m], m\in M$ the product must be $B[m_1]*B[m_2]=B[m_1\cdot m_2]$. I don't think you have that. Here $m_1\cdot m_2$ is the operation of your monoid $M$.

Comment: I assume that your definition of a monoid ring parallels that of the group ring.

Comment: In that case, what exactly do I have here? Would the quaternions not be a Monoid ring since i*i = -1?

Comment: A monoid ring over the reals (or any other commutative ring) has a basis that is closed under multiplication. So, no, quaternions don't form a monoid ring.

Comment: $\Bbb{R}[y]/\langle y^3-y\rangle$ would be a monoid ring. It has a basis of (cosets of) $\{1,y,y^2\}$ and we have $1\cdot y=y$, $1\cdot y^2=y^2$, $y\cdot y=y^2$, $y\cdot y^2=y$, $y^2\cdot y^2=y^2$. All because in this quotient ring $y^3=y$ and $y^4=y^2$. So $\{1,y,y^2\}$ is a monoid. I don't for which polynomials we get a monoid ring, it is a bit delicate. But, you need to exhibit a basis closed under multiplication.

Comment: From what you given it seems any polynomials of the form $$x^{p} - x^{q} = 0; p > q $$ Form a Monoid ring.

Comment: That seems to be the case! Initially I thought it must be $x^n-1$, and that is the only way to get a *groip* ring. Monoids, probably it must be of the form in your comment, but I'm not 100 per cent :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87620/discussion-between-malachi-wadas-and-jyrki-lahtonen).

Answer (score 0):

Multiplicatively, its the monoid (ring extension of $R$) $R[\bar x,\bar y]$, where $\bar x^3 + \bar x - 1 = \bar 0$ and $\bar y^3 - \bar y = \bar 0$.

Comment: This is not what [a monoid ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid_ring) is. If $M$ is a (multiplicative) monoid, the monoid ring $R[M]$ is the ring of formal linear combinations $\sum_{m\in M} r_m m$ with $r_m\in R$ for all $m\in M$, componentwise addition, and multiplication extending $R$-linearly the multiplication in $M$.